# How to refactor many ifs and else with different conditions in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, refactoring

I have many ifs and elses that assign a variable an X value. Does anyone have any idea how to try to improve this code?

I've searched for several ideas on the internet, but I haven't found anything that would help me in this specific case.

```py
date1 = ''
date2 = ''
name = ''

query = ''

if date1 and date2 and name:
    query = 'query 1'
elif date1 and date2:
    query = 'query 2'
elif date1 and name:
    query = 'query 3'
else:
    query = 'query default'
```

Comment: Why are you checking date 1 twice? `if date1 and date1`?

Comment: You have 4 distinct outcomes & seemingly arbitrary conditions for each.  What kind of improvement are you looking for?

Comment: @EmiOB in this case, a write wrong I check for date1 and date2

Comment: @ScottHunter For this case, the code works nice, but I reach for improvement to remove this many IFs if possible, you know?

Comment: Your example is too small for any meaningful answer.

Comment: maybe consider the new pattern match constructs introduced in 3.10

Answer (score 3):

You could eliminate the need for the `else` by initializing `query` with the default value.

Answer (score 1):

You can try mapping your input values to queries

```
# map (date1, date2, name) => query
query_map = {
    (date1, None, None): query1,
    (None, date2, None): query2,
    (date1, None, name): query3,
}

query = query_map.get((input_date1, input_date2, input_name), "default_query")
```

Comment: This won't do the same as the if's. Since your keys are actual strings, not booleans.

Comment: I tried to create a map but had no idea how to do it. I didn't know this idea that you showed, very interesting, thanks so much!

Comment: Should probably be `query_map = {
    (True, True, True): query1,
    (True, True, False): query2,
    (True, False, True): query3,
}` and `query = query_map.get((bool(input_date1), bool(input_date2), bool(input_name)), "default_query")`? Because the empty string `''` is not `None`, and a string is always equal to itself even if empty.

Comment: How is this an improvement?

Answer (score 1):

i think it is overall fine atleast in my opinion. You could use pythons all() function to check if all elements are true. Maybe you could chain the elements differently but still i think its fine. Since Python 3.10 you could use match aswell.

```python
if all(date1,date2):
# do something
```

Comment: Hi, nice idea and use of `all` syntax. Probably, an example of that syntax in the question's context will be helpful. Welcome to Stackovervlow!

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/all

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Using a generator and `next`:

```py
query = next(v for k,v in [(date1 and date2 and name, 'query 1'),
                           (date1 and date2, 'query 2'),
                           (date1 and name, 'query 3'),
                           (True, 'query default')]
               if k)
```

Comment: How is this an improvement?

Comment: @ScottHunter Because all the data (conditions and queries) are in one data structure (a list of pairs) rather than spread over if/else code. Separating data and code is good. This would make even more sense if instead of three variables date1, date2 and name, we had three keys 'date1', 'date2' and 'name' and wanted to check if those keys were in a dictionary: `keys_and_queries = [(['date1' , 'date2',  'name'], 'query 1'), (['date1', 'date2'], 'query 2'), (['date1', 'name'], 'query 3'), ([], 'query default')]` then `query = next(v for ks,v in keys_and_queries if all(k in data for k in ks))`

Comment: @ScottHunter And now you can dynamically modify `keys_and_queries` without modifying the source code.